# Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql5.php): failed to open stream

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a running project on my server, when i try to copy it to my local env i got the following error:

> Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql5.php): failed
>   to open stream

i already setup the `app/etc/local.xml` and delete the `var/cache` folder

Comment: Please make sure the specified folder has proper ownership and read permissions

Comment: @RajMohanR still same issue

Comment: The error states that Mysql5.php file is either missing or it don't have read permissions. So please double check it